# Rendering will_paginate gem UI

Tags: ruby-on-rails, will-paginate

I am using will_paginate gem to install paginations. But I don't know how to format(Put style on its apperance) them. I only see plain text without boxes. See this [link](http://screencast.com/t/GNsIWDAO).   Here's how I do it:

Controller:

```
@listings = Listings.where(:status => "active").paginate(:page => params[:page])
```

View:

```
<div class="dv-pagination"><!--START OF LISTING PAGINATION-->

              <div id="dv-pagination-wrap">
                <div class="e-float-left"><p class="p-listing-available"><%= page_entries_info @listings %></p></div>
                <div class="e-float-right">
                  <%= will_paginate @listings, :id=>'dv-pagination-btns'%>                  
                </div>
                <div class="e-clear-both"></div>
              </div>

            </div><!--END OF LISTING PAGINATION-->
```

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: what do you mean plain text without boxes? do you want to change the styling?

Comment: Here's the link of the image for a clearer view. http://screencast.com/t/GNsIWDAO

Comment: Are you referring to the visual appearance of the pagination links?